# How to create module and import it in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, importerror, python-module

I want to make a module that is in the same directory as the file that imports the module.

For example, if I have a directory "test", the module file is in the directory "test" and another file that is going to import the module is in the directory "test", too.

If the module name is "module_name" and the function in it is "function_name", how can I create that module with that function and import it in another file?

I tried this:

```
from module_name import function_name
```

But it told me that it is an "Unresolved reference"
How can I fix that?
What am I doing wrong?

I'm using

> ```
>  - PyCharm Edu 2018.2  
>  - Python 3.7
> ```

(I tried researching and I didn't get the answer)

Answer (score 1):

If the project directory looks like this:

```
project/test/moduletoimport.py
project/test/modulethatimports.py
```

then the following line in `modulethatimports.py` will import the function you need:

```
from project.test.moduletoimport import function_name
```

Comment: Are you sure it does not work to use `from moduletoimport import func` as well? Using the whole project path might lead to other problems.

Comment: I did exactly that (my directory also look exactly like that) but it still says "Unresolved reference" on both the "from" part and the "import" part. Is it different between using PyCharm and Python itself?

Comment: Yes, pycharm has its own way of thinking... It might be worth it to verify that `test` is a python package, and has an `__init__.py`

Comment: `from test import moduletoimport` works, but `from moduletoimport import func` doesn't. That's very weird of PyCharm.